# What's a fast way to parse a math operator off of a string of numbers?

Tags: vb.net

Given a string as a form of input (parsed from an input file) which represents a number and a mathematical operator (<, >, <=, >=, !, !=, and a few others), what is a really fast, efficient way to chop off that operator, compare it to a list of valid operators, and then set an "operator" variable to a state (i.e., Enum) representing the identified operator, then return just the number (as a string)?

I'm open to various ideas and implementations.  I've tried several (about 6-7) myself, and find I'm not really satisfied with the speed.  The fastest so far is a For Each loop that walks my list of "valid operators", and compares that operator's string representation against the chopped off bit from the numeric string.  I determine the amount to chop off by the length of each valid operator in the valid list.

Here's a code example of the fastest implementation.  Assume input like `<378` and a valid ops list of `<, >, !`, or `>=79` and a valid ops list of `<=, >=`:

```
Friend Function FindMatchingOp(ByVal Haystack As String,
                               ByVal ValidOps() As <OperatorType>) As String
    Dim tmpBit As String, tmpOpName As String, tmpOpLen As Int32

    For Each tmpOp As <OperatorType> In ValidOps
        tmpOpName = tmpOp.Name
        tmpOpLen = tmpOpName.Length
        tmpBit = Strings.Left(Haystack, tmpOpLen)

        If String.Equals(tmpBit, tmpOpName) Then
            <Code to set the correct operator>
            Return Haystack.Remove(0, tmpOpLen)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    Return vbNullString
End Function
```

Not all of the numeric strings I expect to parse will utilize the same math operators (hence the need for the ValidOps variable).  Some might only support < and >, others might do <=, >=, and !.  This is why I cannot hardcode the assumption that the operator will be only one character in length, and have to test for both one-or-two character operators.  I believe it's these specific string checks that slow my other implementations down.

I've also tried putting ValidOps into things like a Dictionary, HashTable, ListDictionary, and even an Arraylist.  The standard array beats all of them every time.

Thoughts?

PS, VB code only, please, in any advice or solutions.

<strike>**EDIT**:
I am going to try and implement a Trie to handle this and see what its performance is.  I got the idea from this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484796/more-efficient-way-to-determine-if-a-string-starts-with-a-token-from-a-set-of-tok).</strike>  Not going to work for me.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you just put these operators on a dropdown list. In this case, it would less error on user input.

Comment: I should have clarified, but when I said "form of input", I meant to state that I will be parsing this in some form from a data file.  It won't be something that a user will manually input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could somewhat improve your function by changing:

```
tmpOpLen = tmpOpName.Length
tmpBit = Strings.Left(Haystack, tmpOpLen)

If String.Equals(tmpBit, tmpOpName) Then
    <Code to set the correct operator>
    Return Haystack.Remove(0, tmpOpLen)
    Exit For
End If
```

to...

```
If Haystack.StartsWith(tmpOp.Name) Then
    <Code to set the correct operator>
    Return Haystack.Remove(0, tmpOp.Name.Length)
    Exit For
End If
```

But that is probably going to be marginal. All you'll have is the removal of all of your intermediate strings.

Comment: Smaller code -- nice, but the execution time in my timing loop increased by ~40ms (per 100,000 iterations) with this implementation.  I assume the code for `StartsWith()` is a little slower than the method I was using.

Comment: I actually wonder if I can roll my own StartsWith version by looking at how it works internally via Reflector.  I know what my specific needs are, and it's possible the .NET version does extra things that I don't need to worry about.

Comment: Scratch that.  My copy of Reflector expired.  I thought they had a free, non-expiring version?  Stupid commercial software.

Comment: Reflector itself is free. Only Reflector Pro (which integrates with VS) requires a license.

Comment: In addition, what are you using to time execution?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to re-visit the website.  The copy I got integrated into VS, but I recall clicking the download link for the freebie.

Comment: Timing loops, a simple loop to increment X times (X being the testing value), and timing with the Stopwatch class.  I also drop the first iteration as that can sometimes be inaccurate due to the code (being tested) getting loaded/run on the first loop.  It's not sophisticated, and probably not really accurate, but it works well enough to identify fast code from slower code.

Comment: I've decided to go with the StartsWith approach for this particular function.  I got the timing between my original implementation and StartsWith to be nearly matched (margin of error accounts for differences), by changing the StringComparison method to `Ordinal`.  Out of the 5-6 implementations I devised, this one just beat all the others out (along with other improvements that I made in my code).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the .NET Regex engine instead of brute-forcing comparisons against a list of operators with that foreach....

A generic way to extract the operator would be:

`String Operator = Regex.Match(MathOperation as String, @"(?=\d*\s*)\w{1,2}(?=\s*)").Value;`

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Drknezz: I already know that initializing the Regex engine itself will add considerable time to each execution of the comparison.  Many of the strings will be far too small to require the degree of functionality that Regex offers.

Comment: No, you can just compile a new Regex object instead of using the static methods and you will only initialize the regex engine once ;)

Comment: @Drknezz: The way I've got this setup, is small classes each handle a number differently.  I.e., `clsObjA` might handle `>7912` and `clsObjB` might handle `!=401`.  So in my timing loop, What I am really testing is an overloaded `FromString()` call in either `clsObjA` or `clsObjB` that takes in the appropriate string and does the work.  My understanding of RegEx is, if I want to compile it once and use everywhere, I'll need to do that at a higher level than each individual object.

Comment: Also, The operator being parsed off is to be converted to a custom Enum that I've designed (I address this in another of my open questions).  So part of my experiment has been involved in converting that string via some fashion to the appropriate strongly-typed Enum object.

Comment: No, just declare a new Regex object and it will work as much as need unless you need to change the regex filter... and a well-designed Regex query will give you the operator you need inmediately, so you can just use a switch or chain some if's to turn the string into your Enum. Hope this clarified things a bit... as Regex totally pwns cycles.

Comment: @Drknezz: what's the VB.Net form of that?  One of these online C# converters appears to not be getting it 100%.

Comment: Its Exactly equal, Regex is ANOTHER language on its own ;) `Dim Operator As String = Regex.Match(MathOperation, @"(?=\d*\s*)\w{1,2}(?=\s*)").Value;` I dont know how to cast stuff in VB :p Id recommend http://regular-expressions.info to get started. Or, C# 4 In a nutshell has an awesome Regex section. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Drknezz: I'm somewhat familiar with RegEx -- used it in Linux quite a bit.  It's not easy to learn (or remember), but quite powerful.  But, I've decided to go with Adam's suggestion.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: I am happy to have helped you anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want, in essence, is a parser for a number followed by an operator. You could do several things: 1. Write a good simple ad-hoc parser. 2. Write a simple inefficient ad-hoc parser (simpler and slower than 1) with for example regexes. 3. Have a parser written for you by a parser-generator (I googled http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/TinyPG.aspx for you).

Your regular grammar here is

```
input := line*
line := number operator
number := digit+
digit := [1-9]
operator := [your|list|of|valid|operator|literals]
```

A simple solution would be to create a recursive decent parser. A fast solution would be to create a finite state automaton parser. A fast lazy (and thus the best) solution is have a parser-generator create a finite state automaton parser for you.